# Service Getting Killed With Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am running an android service, started by calling startService(Intent i), that handles the sound-playing part of an alarm clock app. I am experiencing an issue where the service is stopped if the app is swiped out of the recent apps drawer during the playback of the alarm sound. (The alarm works fine if the app is swiped from recents *before* the alarm goes off)

Below is my code for the service:

```
public class RingerService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer mp;
public static final String ACTION_START = "START";
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "STOP";


@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // No intent, tell the system not to restart us.
        if (intent == null) {
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STOP))
            stopSelf();
        else {
            final AlarmModel alarm =     intent.getParcelableExtra(AlarmsActivity.EXTRA_MODEL);
            Uri alarmTone = alarm.getAlarmTone();
            play(alarmTone);
        }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void play(Uri alarmTone) {
    //TODO: test dealing with stopping previous alarm if it is sounding
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            System.out.println("Audio Playbeck Error");
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
            return true;
        }
    });
    //TODO: lock volume at max!
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, alarmTone);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}

private void stop() {
    if(mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stop();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

I have researched and investigated a few possibilities, but all have turned out to be dead ends. First of all, I do not seem to be binding to the activity in any way, so I don't know why the service would be killed along with the rest of the app.

I had thought that maybe this was related to the service-kill bug in KitKat, but when I ran this same code on a cyanogenmod 10.2 device, the same thing happened.

If I cannot find a solution to this, I may aim to just exclude the app from recent apps as a workaround.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May be try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Implement this code snippet in your service

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```